# Limited results in searchTwitter() or userTimeline()

Tags: r, twitter, text-analysis

I am trying to fetch tweets using `searchTwitter()` and/or `userTimeline()`
I want to fetch maximum number tweets allowed to fetch by twitterR API (I believe that limit is around 3000.)
But in result I'm only getting very few posts (like 83 or 146). I'm sure there are more number of posts, when I check the Timeline of that user (via browser or app) I see there are more than 3000 posts.
Below is the message I get.

```
r_stats <- searchTwitter("#ChangeToMeIs", n=2000)
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit =         retryOnRateLimit,  :
  2000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 83
```

Is there anything I am missing on?

PS: I've checked all related question before posting. Before marking duplicate, please help me with the solution.

Comment: I think you do not ask for a user but for a hastag by `"#ChangeToMeIs"` that. I do it like this `userTimeline('barackobama', n=100)`

Comment: Yes in the example above, I'm trying to get results for that keyword only.

Comment: Now I got new warning:

`r_stats1 <- userTimeline("@SBUT_Mumbai", n=300000)
Warning message:
In statusBase(cmd, params, n, 3200, ...) :
  statuses/user_timeline has a cap of 3200 statuses, clipping`

But still: `> length(r_stats1)
[1] 193`

Why I am not able to fetch maximum cap posts?

Comment: wait I will give you my solution that works fine

Comment: Is there any limitation by twitteR API, for providing only limited data? I've read few posts mentioning that.

Comment: I guess there is some API restriction due to the date. For myself I made a simple .bat file that run the R code every day and download twitts from the past 24 h. Otherwise there is restricted number of days back you can import twitts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are using is the `Twitter Search API` and it only returns a sample of results, not the comprehensive search.

What you need is Twitter Streaming API.

> Please note that the Twitter search API does not return an exhaustive
>   list of tweets that match your search criteria, as Twitter only makes
>   available a sample of recent tweets. For a more comprehensive search,
>   you will need to use the Twitter streaming API, creating a database of
>   results and regularly updating them, or use an online service that can
>   do this for you.

Source: https://colinpriest.com/2015/07/04/tutorial-using-r-and-twitter-to-analyse-consumer-sentiment/

Answer (score 0):

I install the `library twitteR` from `git hub`  and this is quite important that the version is from `git` not `CRAN`
Than set up

```
setup_twitter_oauth("xxxxxxx", "xxxxx")
```

and than you can use the commends as

To get twitts from users timeline

```
  ut <- userTimeline('xxxx', n=2000)
    ut <- twListToDF(ut)
```

or to search for specific hastags

```
tweets<-twListToDF(searchTwitter("#f1", n=5000))
```

It works perfect for me

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_1.1-12         httr_1.1.0         rjson_0.2.15       plyr_1.8.3         R6_2.1.2           rsconnect_0.4.1.11 DBI_0.3.1          tools_3.2.2       
 [9] whisker_0.3-2      yaml_2.1.13        Rcpp_0.12.4        bit64_0.9-5        rCharts_0.4.5      RJSONIO_1.3-0      grid_3.2.2         lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: Ok @Mateusz1981 I had twitteR installed from `Cran` previously I installed it from `GIT` and tried, I could see no change in behaviour. Still I could fetch only 198 tweets. :(

Comment: Than I guess there is some API restriction due to the date

Answer (score 0):

Since `twitteR` is going to be deprecated, what you need to do is install `rtweet`.

Here is the code:

```
# Install and load the 'rtweet' package
install.packages("rtweet")
library(rtweet)    

# whatever name you assigned to your created app
appname <- "tweet-search-app"

# api key (example below is not a real key)
key <- "9GmBeouvgfdljlBLryeIeqCHEt"

# api secret (example below is not a real key)
secret <- "ugdfdgdgrxOzjhlkhlxgdxllhoiofdtrrdytszghcv"

# create token named "twitter_token"
twitter_token <- create_token(
                 app = appname,
                 consumer_key = key,
                 consumer_secret = secret)

# Retrieve tweets for a particular hashtag
r_stats <- search_tweets("#ChangeToMeIs", n = 2000, token = twitter_token)
```